# Calculate limit sequence of roots equation $f(x) = g(x)$.

Tags: limits

Considering the functions $\;f,g:(0,\frac{\pi}{2})\rightarrow \textbf{R}\;$ given by $f(x)=\tan x, \;g(x)=nx,\;$ 
where $n\in\textbf{N}, n\neq0\,$ defines the sequence $\,x_{n}\,$ given by the roots of the equation $f(x) = g(x)$, namely $f(x_{n}) = g(x_{n})$. 
Find $\;\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{n}$.

Using the graphical representation of functions $ f $ and $ g $ can be seen easily that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{n}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

This is the only way?

Comment: Type \$\tan\$ and \$\lim\$ instead of what you did. I also suggest you type \$\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\$ instead of \$\lim _{n\to +\infty}\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $x_n$ is uniquely determined (easy to show).

Next, show that the graph of $\frac{ \tan x} { x} $ is strictly increasing on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. This requires differentiation.

Hence, conclude that the limit exists, and is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You might note that for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$, 
$\dfrac{\tan(x)}{x}$ (which has a limit of $1$ at $x=0$) is bounded on $(0,\pi/2 - \epsilon]$.  So for 
$n$ large enough,  we must have $x_n > \pi/2 - \epsilon$.